# slider image stretched [com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout]

Tags: android

I am creating a slider for my android app using the library `com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout`, but the problem I am facing is that pictures with small width are stretched while showing in the slider which looks a bit odd. How to fix that i.e., for small width images they should appear without stretching. Below is my code, can we do any alteration here

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        />
```

Comment: How are you loading the image inside an ImageView?

Comment: this is external library . please check whether `android:scaleType="Center"` is  working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the library and what I found was, when you are loading the image there are multiple scale types available.

Like these

```
BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop
BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterInside
BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit
BaseSliderView.ScaleType.FitCenterCrop
```

you can set it like this

```
TextSlide slide = new TextSlider(this)
        .image(url)
        .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterInside);
        // other properties

slider.addSlide(slide);
```

Replace `TextSlider()`with whatever type you want and `setScaleType()` to whatever suits for you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, this line of Slider solved the problem --

```
.setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.FitCenterCrop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the xml codes :

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                        android:id="@+id/slider"
                        app:pager_animation="Fade"
                        app:auto_cycle="true"
                        app:indicator_visibility="visible"
                        app:pager_animation_span="1100"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         />
```

Use and enjoy ...